# What might be reason for terminating Tomcat7 process

Tags: java, tomcat, process

We have a Tomcat7-hosted webapp, and sometimes Tomcat just stops listening to the ports it should (and we get a Zabbix notification)

As it appears, in catalina.out I see the non-standard strings begin with:

```
8 1:16:45.305 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2] IMPORTANT::TERMINATE_SIGNALED
net.sf.apr.eflow.Shutdown$ShowStackTrace: null
        at net.sf.apr.eflow.Shutdown.terminate(Shutdown.java:296) [net_sf_apr.jar:na]
        at net.sf.apr.web.ShutdownListener.stop(ShutdownListener.java:157) [net_sf_apr.jar:na]
        at net.sf.apr.web.ShutdownListener.contextDestroyed(ShutdownListener.java:199) [net_sf_apr.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4830) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.28.jar:7.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5477) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.28.jar:7.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.28.jar:7.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1611) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.28.jar:7.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1600) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.28.jar:7.0.28]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_72]
```

So I suspect the process was terminated by something ..

as I run "service tomcat7 status", I get smth like "Tomcat is not running, but PID file exists"

So I have to "service tomcat7 start" in order to get it running

How can I locate this problem ? I've looked at the syslog but there's nothing very relevant.

What might cause a Tomcat process to be terminated this way ? This is on Debian 7, and Tomcat is run as:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx16G -XX:MaxPermSize=15G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Comment: What log messages precede that stacktrace? Maybe there is hint in them.

Comment: Before this line everything seems to be pretty much routine. The process catches a SIG_TERM signal; that's pretty clear. but WHY does that happen ?

Comment: Can you provide the logs, @62mkv?

Comment: well, that's difficult.. it has a HUGE lots of information and luckily the problem does not occur very often, so those particular logs will be different to find; and also they contain a lot of proprietary information, which I would not like to share a lot. Can you just take my word on it, that in both cases (it goes about DIFFERENT webapps on DIFFERENT servers), the preceding logging records are ABSOLUTELY routine

Comment: Also, I could reproduce the whole thing by just issuing "kill <pid>" command with a PID of Tomcat process. It behaves exactly at it happened before - normal activity in the logs; then IMPORTANT::TERMINATE_SIGNALED message, and "tomcat is not running but pid file exists" result of "service tomcat7 status" command. So it's almost 100% sure that someting EXTERNAL terminates the process, may be "out-of-memory killer". I'll try to research this

Comment: I've read thru this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html and tried to find indication that the process was indeed killed by OOM. Unfortunately, there's no message like "..killed..." in /var/log/messages.*.